# Html table data gets overlapped in Chrome

Tags: html, width, html-table

I have a html table with 5 columns and multiple rows. First column consists of labels and others with textboxes. The number of columns may vary based on the data.

Width for each column is equally assigned by percentage (100% divided by number of columns).

In IE, first column (Labels) gets expanded automatically if the label text is long. But in Chrome its not expanding.

Please suggest me which style i need to apply for the first column?

**Following is the server side code for Table:**

```
        TableRow headerRow = new TableRow();
        foreach (string s in columns)
        {
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Width = Unit.Percentage(100.00 / colsCount);
            cell.BorderColor = Color.White;
            cell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label tb = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label();
            //tb.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
            //tb.Width = Unit.Percentage(100.00);
            //tb.Height = Unit.Pixel(45);


            tb.ID = "TextHeaderBoxRow" + s;
            tb.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(211, 230, 254);
            tb.BorderColor = Color.White;
            tb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
            tb.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(0);
            tb.Font.Bold = true;
            tb.Text = s;
            //tb.Attributes.Add("style", "overflow :hidden");
            tb.Font.Name = "Tahoma";
            tb.Font.Size = FontUnit.Point(9);
            //tb.ReadOnly = true;
            tb.TabIndex = -1;

            cell.Controls.Add(tb);
            headerRow.Cells.Add(cell);
        }
        Table1.Rows.Add(headerRow);

        // Now iterate through the table and add your controls 
        for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            row.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.PaddingRight, "5px");
            row.Width = Unit.Percentage(100.00);

            for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++)
            {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.BorderColor = Color.White;
                cell.Width = Unit.Percentage(100.00 / colsCount);
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.Width = Unit.Percentage(100.00);
                tb.Font.Name = "Tahoma";
                tb.Font.Size = FontUnit.Point(9);
                tb.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:Changeflag()");
                tb.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "javascript:Changeflag()");

                // Set a unique ID for each TextBox added
                tb.ID = "TextBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j;

                // Add the control to the TableCell
                cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                // Add the TableCell to the TableRow
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
            }
            // Add the TableRow to the Table
            Table1.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Comment: Can you post some code or a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is following what you are telling it to do.  You specify that all the widths should be equal and so it is wrapping the label.  IE is doing what you want, but not what you told it to do.

If you aren't able to specify the width of the first column to be large enough to not have any wrapping, you could try adding `white-space=nowrap` to the styling for the labels.

Comment: I applied the "White-space:nowrap" style but its not working for Chrome